# RN notifee and firebase doesn't sound and show badge number in iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification

I'm working with react native a need that appears the badge numbers and sound in iOS when the app is background but that is not working, I'm using notifee and firebase, when app is foreground working good the problem is when is background.

```
messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
        id: 'default',
        name: 'Default Channel',
      });
      await notifee.displayNotification({
        title: remoteMessage.data?.title || '',
        body: remoteMessage.data?.message || '',
        data: {
          title: remoteMessage.data?.title || '',
          message: remoteMessage.data?.message || '',
          type: remoteMessage.data?.type || '',
        },
        android: {
          channelId,
          importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
          color: LightTheme.colors.primary,
          smallIcon: 'notification_icon',
          largeIcon: 'notification_icon',
          pressAction: {
            id: 'stop',
          },
        },
        ios: {
          badgeCount: 1,
          sound: 'default',
          foregroundPresentationOptions: {
            alert: true,
            badge: true,
            sound: true,
          },
        },
      });
    }); 

 messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async () => {
      await notifee.incrementBadgeCount();
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since push notification are handled by iOS and not your app you can't change the application badge on receiving a push notification.
But you can send the badge number in the payload of the push notification, which will be apply to app icon but for this you will have to do the calculation server side.
[You should read Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1) and especially the [The Notification Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1).
The payload could look like this:

```
// Payload for remote Notification to APN
{
    "aps": {
        "content-available": 1,
        "alert": "Hallo, this is a Test.",
        "badge": 2, // This is your Int which will appear as badge number,
        "sound": default
    }
}
```

Sound : default
will play the default sound  for custom sound for notification
You should place your sound file in android/app/res/raw and  for iOS you should place your sound file in Resource in appname.xcodeproj  file
Now the app application badge icon will show 2 badge count on app icon . And play your custom sound